# Using YII widgets in JS disabled browser

Tags: php, javascript, html, yii

Can we design Sites with YII framework (as REST)  + client side MVC JS frameworks such that -

By default HTML gets rendered from JS templates in browser's client. 
But, when JS is disabled in browser, then its falls back to YII widgets and they render it server side ?

Or if not this, please suggest some design principle for most simply handling this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i getting this wrong but using the `<noscript>`-tag should be working for this problem.